# Grammar check - made able to

Tags: grammar

> The device must be made able to tend to emergencies on its own.

Is the above statement grammatically correct? Is there any other way to mean "to be made able to"?

Comment: You could always drop *made*. Unless the context is one of invention and you're talking about what somebody must *do* rather just describing the device. But that's the only slight issue I see; either way, it's grammatical.

Comment: **to be made able** is **to enable**. (Alternatively, **configured, capable of tending)

Comment: I feel enabled would be a little off the mark. But none the less, a viable option. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> The device must be made able to tend to emergencies on its own.

Yes, this appears grammatical, however an awkward phrasing.

A few alternatives:

> 1. The device must be (enhanced/modified/updated/repaired/improved) so that it's able to tend to emergencies on its own.
> 2. The device must be constructed in such a way that it's able to tend to emergencies on its own.
> 3. The device must be able to tend to emergencies on its own.

Options #1 or #2 retains a close meaning to the original.
Option #3 is a good choice since it's simple and clear. (if it's acceptable to drop the word "made", which may or may not be the case depending on the context.)